# Cups Service in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, cups

I am using  "Debian 3.10.5-1~bpo70+1". Generally after a shutdown / restart, CUPS service is not automatically started.

1) What could be the reasons other then if not specifically implemented by the Sys-Admins?

2) Is there any security issue if I add a group with privilege to start the CUPS service and assign the group to each user.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if any further details needed.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

- The startup daemon which is supposed to be run automatically at startup is not being executed
- The daemon is being executed, but something has changed and it bombs out before completing.

Immediately after startup, look at the files in `/var/log` that are newer than the time of startup (each file is written FIFO).